# aspnet_regiis - not in the path on Server, but is on Windows 10?

Tags: .net

While working on encrypting web.config sections, I discovered that on Windows 2012-R2, aspnet_regiis is NOT in the path, but on my Windows 10 workstation, it is.

How can it it be inconsistent in this way?

(On Server, it is a hassle to get to the right .NET dir across many systems)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ack, I think I see it.

If I first

```
cd C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319
```

Then aspnet_regiis is the FULL utility.

But the one in the path is from (I believe) the local iis I run for dev.